# Returning variable´s value from first function and using it in second function

Tags: jquery, variables, click

So i want to click an item inside a list and get the index of that item. Clicking on an item will reveal the content element. And clicking on that content element should give me the (index +1) of the item that i clicked in the first place. So far im getting 'NaN' error. What exactly am i doing wrong? Passing normal string values seems to work.

```
<div class="item-list">
  <div class="item">Item1</div>
  <div class="item">Item2</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden" style="display: none">Content</div>
```

---

```
$(function() {
    var thisIndex;
    $('.item-list .item').click(function(event) {
       var thisIndex = $('.item-list .item').index(this)
       $('.hidden').css('display', 'block')
    });
    $('.hidden').click(function(event) {  
       var nextIndex = thisIndex + 1;
       console.log(nextIndex)
    });
})
```

js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zv0Lza6n/4/

Comment: What makes you think a variable declared in one function, would be accessible in another function? If you want to use the outer variable, remove `var` from within the function.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zv0Lza6n/5/

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your `thisIndex` variable outside your click function, and then *again* inside the click function. Declare it once and then assign it a value in the function.

```
$(function() {
    var thisIndex; 

    $('.item-list .item').click(function(event) {
        thisIndex = $('.item-list .item').index(this);
      $('.hidden').css('display', 'block');
    });
    $('.hidden').click(function(event) {  
      var nextIndex = thisIndex + 1;
      console.log(nextIndex);
    });
});
```

You were also missing a few semicolons.